# Is review history not public in private beta?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I just crossed 350 and now can see review queue but not able to see review history. On clicking History option for any review it only shows my own reviews. But in Other site graduated or Public beta i can see all review history. Is it happening just to me or  review history in Private beta kept Private?

Comment: This seems unintentional. I'll have an ask internally to see what comes up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Viewing the full history for any queue is a "mod tools" privilege. We just added a small note on this to the mod tools privilege wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I am only 3K on Stack Overflow, and I can only see my own history, but I am 10K on Meta Stack Overflow and I can see all.  I think it is a 10K privilege (or the beta equivalent), so I am virtually certain this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: "Moderator tools" is kind of vague and, AFAIK, not enumerated anywhere, but it does seems to me that the review history is one of the things included under that heading. So it should be a 1K privilege here.

Comment: Ohhh...its the case. I noticed that i am also unable to see review history on SO because of 1k rep but can see it in Movies and TV beta because i have 9k+ rep there.